# SHA256.Create() always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sha

Whenever I use the `SHA256.Create()` method it always returns a null value. Here is the method I have for encrypting a password ...

```
private string EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    SHA256 sha = SHA256.Create(password);
    return BitConverter.ToString(sha.Hash);
}
```

The debugger shows that the variable `sha` is null. I have even tried putting it in its own method in a controller but I still get a `System.NullReferenceException`

```
public String Index()
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(SHA256.Create("Hello World").Hash);
}
```

I am completely lost. Is there something that I am obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Create()` isn't meant for the message, it specifies the SHA256 implementation.

I suspect you want to use the implementation class `SHA256Managed` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256managed.aspx

Example:

```
using (var sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
{
    byte[] raw = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
    return sha256.ComputeHash(raw);
}
```

Comment: +1, followed by a call to ComputeHash (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a.aspx) to compute the actual hash value.

Comment: It seems the the output of `ComputeHash()` delimits the hash with `-` every two characters. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Sbossb How are you displaying the hash'd value?

Comment: I'm converting the byte[] to a String using BitConverter.ToString() and then storing it into the database as a nchar(64)

Comment: @Sbossb That's BitConverter adding the -.  You could just do BitConverter.ToString(xxx).Replace("-", string.Empty);  ... or convert to Base64: Convert.ToBase64String(xxx)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Silly mistake because I didn't read the documentation carefully

Comment: you bet.  for what it's worth, we found it to be slooooow and ended up using an highly optimized version of SHA256 instead.  not sure if it'll be a bottleneck for your application.